# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - Core Data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fatal-error

I am getting this wrapping error when I implement my fetched managed object core data code. Currently getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. What am I doing wrong?

**ViewController:**

```
 func saveRun() {
            // 1
            let savedRun = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext!) as! Run
            savedRun.distance = NSNumber(value: distance)
            savedRun.duration = (NSNumber(value: seconds))
            savedRun.timestamp = NSDate() as Date



            // 2
            var savedLocations = [Location]()
            for location in locations {
                let savedLocation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Location",
                                                                        into: managedObjectContext!) as! Location
                savedLocation.timestamp = (location.timestamp as NSDate) as Date
                savedLocation.latitude = NSNumber(value: location.coordinate.latitude)
                savedLocation.longitude = NSNumber(value: location.coordinate.longitude)
                savedLocations.append(savedLocation)
            }
            savedRun.locations = NSOrderedSet(array: savedLocations)
            run = savedRun

            do{
                try managedObjectContext!.save()
            }catch{
                print("Could not save the run!")
            }
        }
```

**App Delegate:**

```
  // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.zedenem.MarathonRun" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return urls.last!
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MarathonRun", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MarathonRun")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [AnyHashable: Any]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error

            print("Error: \(error.domain)")
            abort()
        }
        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)//NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            if moc.hasChanges{
                do{
                    try moc.save()
                }catch let error as NSError{
                    print("Error: \(error.domain)")
                }
            }
        }
```

Please check screenshots [image]
[image]

Comment: Why are `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectContext` optional? If the creation of the coordinator fails you get a fatal error (`abort()`) anyway and the app terminates. Both instances are supposed to be **non-optional**. And the init method `init(managedObjectModel` of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` returns a non-optional instance, too. Why do you annotate the type as optional and make it worse?

Comment: But what's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the compiler will tell you.

Comment: All shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Your `managedObjectContext` object is `nil` and you have forced wrapped it with `!` which will cause the crash.

So before you do this:

```
let savedRun = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext!) as! Run
```

Make sure you have a value for `managedObjectContext`:

```
if let managedObjectContext = [get the managedObjectContext object here] {
     // If you succeed with getting the managedObjectContext, then you can use it without the ! in here
     let savedRun = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext) as! Run
}
```

Comment: @faig-huseynov : I believe the answer above is correct hence up voted. Now as per your question of why ? May I know how are u accessing managedObject Context in your VC ??

Comment: Are you asking about this? 
 `var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?`

Comment: @FaigHuseynov, where you set the `managedObjectContext` change that and set it by using `if let` instead as I explained in the answer.

Comment: @FaigHuseynov, if my answer was useful, click the upvote button to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some investigation by reading the comments the reason of the crash is most likely that you are only **declaring** the managed object context

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
```

but not **initializing** it in the view controller. So it remains `nil` and causes the crash.

A suitable way to get the context from AppDelegate is a lazy instantiated property

```
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.managedObjectContext
}()
```

Now your `saveRun()` method is supposed to work.

---

By the way: **Do not** initialize `persistentStoreCoordinator` and `managedObjectContext` in AppDelegate as optional. That's nonsense. The app is unfeasible and will terminate anyway if the coordinator could not be created.

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MarathonRun")
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [AnyHashable: Any]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error

        print("Error: ", error)
        abort()
    }
    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)//NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

Another cumbersome code is the dance to convert `Double` to `NSNumber` and vice versa. It's perfectly legal to declare `latitude` and `longitude` in the `NSManagedObject` subclass as `Double`. Same thing are `date` attributes. Declare them as `Date` to avoid a lot of type casting.

Comment: Do you think that you need to remove persistentStoreCoordinator and managedObjectContext?

Comment: No, not remove. The objects are necessary (in AppDelegate). But don't declare them as optional.

Comment: Where declare them as optional?
I think I missed something so it crumbles

Comment: Once again: Do **NOT** declare both lazy properties as optional, replace both properties  in AppDelegate –  `lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator` and `lazy var managedObjectContext` – with my code and remove all exclamation marks when you access the context.

Answer (score -1):

you can use if let ,So you app will not crash.

```
if  let savedRun = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Run", into: managedObjectContext!) as! Run {



}
```

But for permanent fix, Please recheck for Run Entity class.